# How can I know what graphics card my motherboard can handle?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I want to upgrade my old office PC with a graphics card that lets me at least play some games, however, a week ago I bought a graphics card (GT 1030), but, when I tried to use it, it wasn't compatible.  My screen just showed the BIOS screen and nothing happened thereafter.

I thought the only requirement was to have a PCIe 2.0 or 3.0, and enough space, because I saw some pages that said that, but then I realized there were more to it thanks to a video I saw.

I tried checking compatibles GPUs in the pc-specs pages, but I don't trust that, because every motherboard has exactly the same compatibles nVIDIA GPUs.

How can I find a compatible GPU?

My motherboard is Pegatron Corporation 2AC2.

Comment: Your motherboard can support any PCIe GPU.  Your PSU or case is another story.  I am not aware of any PCIe 4.0 GPUs so that isn’t a concern.  Please provide specifics about your motherboard by performing an [edit] to your question.

Comment: I have a 300w PSU, thats the PSU requirements for GT 1030, thats why I thought it was the motherboard, anyways I edited the question

Comment: PCIe 3.0 devices are backwards compatible with PCIe 2.0 slots but that comes with a performance penalty.  I suspect the card wasn’t getting enough power

Comment: You need at least a 500w PSU.

Answer (score 0):

How to know if a graphics card is compatible: Find the PCI Express slot. On many PCs, there will be a few expansion slots on the motherboard. Typically they will all be PCI Express, but for a graphics card you need a PCI Express x16 slot.
There are three versions of this slot, but they’re backwards compatible, so a modern PCI Express 3.0 graphics card will work in a motherboard with a PCI Express x16 2.0 slot.